# Querying data from tables from two different databases on different SQL servers with different sign in credentials

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I would like to select data from two tables from two databases in different Microsoft SQL Server 2017 instances in one query.

For the one server, I sign in using my windows authentication credentials associated with my Windows account and for the second server, I sign in using a username and password as my Windows account doesn't have permission to the server.

What I tried is to :

- First of all [link the two servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)
- Then I use an [openquery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) and execute a `SELECT` pass-through query

But it seems to not work and I would like to ask, how I can additionally set the credentials for the second server (who I can access by a username and password) in the above method or by using a better approach.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you set the linked server credentials using this: `EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin` ? You can see full documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedsrvlogin-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Actually I haven't, I will try it thank you!